# How would I put an integer that is storing numbers into an array?

Tags: java

So I have an integer z that is holding the values of zip codes and i need to store each digit of the zip code in a separate part of the array. How would i be able to do this?

```
 private int [] zipDigits = new int [5];
 private int digitCheck;
 private int zipCode;
 public ZipCode(int z)
 {
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    zipDigits[i] = 
this.zipCode = z;
```

Comment: Could you please clarify? show an example of what you mean.

Comment: Show your code? This site is mainly about questions that you need help answering, not for complete answers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
public int[] intToDigits(int z) {
    int n = String.valueOf(z).length();
    int[] res = new int[n];
    int i = n - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
        res[i--] = z % 10;
        z = z / 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

This first gets the length in a quite obvious matter, you could also do this using logarithms but I don't know if their precision would lead to issues. Then starts at the back of the array, takes the last digit with mod and then deletes this digit by dividing the number by 10.

EDIT:
I now see that you've edited your post to state that the length is known to be 5 digits, then we don't need to calculate the length ourselves and we can use the following algorithm:

```
public int[] intToDigits(int z) {
    int[] res = new int[5];
    int i = 4;
    while (i >= 0) {
        res[i--] = z % 10;
        z = z / 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Everybody convert it into a string. These are heavy operations. Since he know the length it's not necessary.

Comment: Yeah he edited the known length in while I was typing this solution, with a known length you could just delete the line for n and replace n with 5 everywhere. Then you get rid of the String operation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the number of digits, you can make a loop getting the rest of division for 10 and saving it into the array and then dividing for 10.

```
int zipCode = 1000;
int [] myArray = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if(zipCode > 0){
        myArray[i] = zipCode%10;
        zipCode /= 10;
    }
    else
        myArray[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are asking this;

you have a

```
 int zip = 90210
```

and you want to put this into a array like this

```
  int [] zipArrary = new int [5];
  String changeZip = Integer.toString(zip);
 for (int i = 0; i < changeZip.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int place = Character.getNumericValue(c);
    zipArray[i] = place;      

  }
```

Something like this?

Comment: He knows the number of digits. So is not necessary transform it into a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
int zip = 12345;
String strZip = Integer.toString(zip);
char[] charArrayZip = strZip.toCharArray();
```

Now your zip is in an array of `char`.

Comment: he wants an array of int.

Comment: Nowhere is that mentioned. From what I gather the OP wants to access the individual characters of a zip code, which the above code does. Once any changes to the individual elements are complete it can be converted back to a single int zip code if needed.

Comment: His code shows him declaring an array of ints and trying to store numbers in it... I'd say that's pretty clearly what he wants to do.

Comment: The point is, it is now accessible as an array, the individual elements of which can be used however needed. The question is vague, at best, as to what he actually wants. The code supplied gives little to no information to what he wants, but looks more like a broken snippet of his current code.